# Pandas: Matching values to get a complete route

Tags: python, pandas, split, dummy-variable

I am trying to match values within the current dataframe to another dataframe to help determine if the value is part of the route. For Example:

```
DF1
    Route    Latitude  Longitude
0    0C,5       1.23    1.23
1   2A,5,1      2.23    2.23
2    5,0C       3.23    3.23

DF2
    In_Route    Rides  
0      5        30    
1      0C       50    
2      1        20
```

Using DF1 and DF2 I would like to match them to create a new column in DF2 to ultimately get the dataframe as shown below:

```
DF2
    In_Route    Rides  Complete_Route_Index
0      5        30         0,1,2
1      0C       50         0,2
2      1        20         1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `list comprehension` with filtering by membership of values of `dict`:

```
d = DF1.Route.to_dict()

f = lambda x: ','.join([str(k) for k, v in d.items() if x in v])
DF2['new'] = DF2['In_Route'].apply(f)
print (DF2)
  In_Route  Rides    new
0        5     30  0,1,2
1       0C     50    0,2
2        1     20      1
```